# renaming jstree node problem

Tags: javascript, jstree

I use the following code to rename jstree node (with crrm plugin):

```
$('#categoriesTree').jstree('rename');
```

How do I know whether the node was successfully renamed (by pressing Enter) or renaming was cancelled (by pressing Esc)? Event 'rename_node.jstree' doesn't provide useful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't know it by built-in functions but you can modify jquery.jstree.js.
In non-compressed version find string `_show_input : function (obj, callback)` (near line 1263) and you'll see:

```
"blur" : $.proxy(function () {
    var i = obj.children(".jstree-rename-input"),
        v = i.val();
    if(v === "") { v = t; }
    h1.remove();
    i.remove(); // rollback purposes
    this.set_text(obj,t); // rollback purposes
    this.rename_node(obj, v);
    callback.call(this, obj, v, t);
    obj.css("position","");
    console.log('click outside or blur after esc / enter'); 
}, this),
"keyup" : function (event) {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if(key == 27) { this.value = t; this.blur(); 
         console.log('press esc'); 
         return; }
    else if (key == 13) { 
         this.blur(); 
         console.log('press enter'); 
         return; 
    } else {
        h2.width(Math.min(h1.text("pW" + this.value).width(),w));
    }
}, //...
```

I added three lines here (`console.log`) and now you can see in console what's happening with your node. Instead of `console.log` you can add some class to your element as flag and read it later or make your custom event, but I don't know how to do this. It's up to you.